# Mysterious Typescript error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, graphics, raphael, typescript

I'm trying to hack up a little game with Typescript and RaphaelJs. So far the code is very short:

```
/// <reference path="raphael-2.1.d.ts"/>
window.onload = () => {
    var paper: RaphaelPaper = Raphael(10, 50, 500, 500);
    var time: Date =new Date();
    var now = time.getTime();
    var elapsedTime = time.getTime() - now;
    var gameObjects = new GameObject[];
    var robot =new Robot( paper.rect(10, 10, 100, 100));
    robot.elem.attr("fill", "green");
    gameObjects.push(robot);
    while (true) {

        elapsedTime = time.getTime() - now;
        gameObjects.forEach((object) => object.update(elapsedTime));
        //gameObjects.forEach((object) => object.draw(paper));
    }
}

interface GameObject{
    update(time:number);
}

class Robot implements GameObject{
    public x: number;
    public y: number;
    public elem: RaphaelElement;
    constructor(element: RaphaelElement) { 
        this.elem = element;
        this.x = this.elem.attr("x");
        this.y = this.elem.attr("y");
    }
    public update(time: number) {
        this.x += 1;
        this.y += 1;
        this.elem.attr("x", this.x);
        this.elem.attr("x", this.y);
    }
}
```

When the page has finished loading a new RaphaelPaper and a list of GameObjects is created. Each GameObject needs to implement one method: update. The idea is that every RaphaelElement that is created during the gameplay is stored in a concrete implementation of GameObject and updated according to its specs.

Let's suppose enemies are small blue rectangles. In order to add these enemies to my game, I would add a class Enemy that implements GameObject and has a special update method that moves the enemy towards the player and checks for an intersection. The robot object is just a very simple example.

The code seems fine to me and VisualStudio marks nothing as wrong but when I try to run the game, an error message pops up and informs me that:

> Error 1   The command "tsc --sourcemap "...strategy go\game.ts"
>   "...strategy go\raphael-2.1.d.ts" "...strategy go\app.ts"" exited with code
>   1.    ...strategy go\strategy go.csproj   85  5   strategy go

I'm sure that this has nothing to do with my IDE setup since another typescript/raphaelJs project works great. Unfortunately I'm unable to get any useful information out of the error message.

UPDATE:
After commenting out `gameObjects.forEach((object) => object.update(elapsedTime));` the project compiles without error. VisualStudio says "build succeeded" and Chrome opens up. But the page never finished loading. Even as I type this, I'm not even seeing the text from the html file.

**UPDATE 2:**
I exchanged the while loop with window.setInterval, now the error is gone AND the page loads. But that's not the classic game loop. I would like to know why a simple while loop prevents my page from loading. That just seems paradox since the while loop is executed in window.onload.

Comment: I'll trim it down, thanks for the hint

Comment: I've replaced the long file paths with ...

Comment: What I mean is that that the command gets truncated causing confusion in the compiler.

Comment: Hm, if I comment out the call to gameObjects.forEach(...) it compiles without error, but the page never loads

Comment: Fewer files, shorter directory name...

Comment: Jan Dvorak, no offense meant but I think you're wrong. Just commenting out the line inside the while loop has removed the compiler error. Now the page doesn't load. In order to follow your advice I deleted app.ts which wasn't needed in the project. Fewer files had no effect at all

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21837/discussion-between-lhk-and-jan-dvorak)

Comment: Not sure if it would affect anything (I've seen odder things on JavaScript errors) but shouldn't "var paper: RaphaelPaper = Raphael(10, 50, 500, 500);" be "var paper: RaphaelPaper = NEW Raphael(10, 50, 500, 500);"?

Comment: Joel Cochran, I think Raphael is a factory method that returns a RaphaelPaper instance. Otherwise it would be var paper:RaphaelPaper=new RaphaelPaper(10,50,500,500); but you're right, one can never be sure with javascript. I'll try that one tomorrow since it's past midnight in Germany

Comment: Joel Cochran, makes no difference for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your original TypeScript error (you can usually see the error itself by viewing the Output window when you build your project in Visual Studio), but as to why your page would freeze during the while (true) { } loop is because you have created an infinite blocking loop.  JavaScript runs in a single threaded process, so what your original loop was doing was blocking anything else from happening in the window.

JavaScript also executes code on a queue based kind of system, what setInterval(fn, delay) does is actually add the function to the queue to be executed once the delay is hit (and this is also how we achieve asynchronous programming in JavaScript). Thus, setInterval(fn, 0) doesn't actually execute the code immediately (though it may seem to do so), but will add the function to the top of the queue, execute other code in the queue, and then execute your function when it gets to it (so if you are evaluating execution time, depending on everything that is happening in your code, your code may not execute at 0ms like you specified).

Also because of this, if you are trying to achieve a game loop with a consistent frame rate, you shouldn't rely on the 'delay' argument of the setInterval function, as this can even vary depending on browser.  You should keep track of your own time intervals and elasped time if frame rate consistency is important in your game.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding setInterval. I'm passing the elapsedTime to each call to update. But I don't understand how an infinite loop in window.onload can prevent the page from loading. If I remember correctly, window.onload was called as soon as the page had finished loading, so why is the html text not displayed ?

Comment: I tried the same with jQuery and it ran fine. After replacing window.onload with $ the page loaded even with the loop. I guess this problem was just one of the quirks of javascript. With that the question is completely solved and I'll gladly accept your answer